# Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock. Error while testing ViewModels in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-testing, kotlin-android-extensions

Trying to test ViewModel in Android.
But I am getting the below error for the below test function.

Wanted but not invoked:
userRepoHelper.getAllUsers();
-> at com.packages.projects.view.utils.UsersApiTest$givenServerResponse200_whenFetch_shouldReturnSuccess$1.invokeSuspend(UserApiTest.kt:50)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

specifically this line is causing the problem

```
verify(userRepoHelper).getAllUsers()
```

```
@Test
    fun givenServerResponse200_whenFetch_shouldReturnSuccess() {
        testCoroutineRule.runBlockingTest {
            val applicationMock = mock(Application::class.java)
            doReturn(emptyList<User>())
                .`when`(userRepoHelper)
                .getAllUsers()
            val viewModel = UsersViewModel(applicationMock)
            viewModel.appServiceList.observeForever(apiUsersObserver)
            verify(userRepoHelper).getAllUsers()
            verify(apiUsersObserver).onChanged(AppServiceResponse.success(emptyList()))
            viewModel.appServiceList.removeObserver(apiUsersObserver)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It means that `userRepoHelper.getAllUsers()` was not invoked inside `UserViewModel`

Are you sure that `userRepoHelper.getAllUsers()` invoked inside the `UserViewmodel` constructor?
Could you share `UserViewModel` code?